# Set numeric UILabel for Auto Layout to correctly compute the intrinsic content size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with a font of size 50 and text `1`. At runtime, its text is changed to other numbers.

If I, say, center it in its `superview`, the automatically detected (intrinsic content size) height is a lot bigger than the actual text, and this is because it tries not to crop other lower characters like `g`.

The thing is that I know I won't use other characters than digits. I also don't want to set a fixed height constraint for it.

Comment: why you don't set the number of lines to 1?

Comment: It is set to `1`.

Comment: `UIFont` metrics include ascender, descender, cap height, x height, etc... all of which determines how the characters fit into a container (here's a good diagram https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/). If you *really* want to get the height (and/or width) of the individual character "glyphs" you'll need to use Core Text. Lots of discussions and example code out there... Good starting point is searching for `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`

Comment: @DonMag, I used a workaround to get rid of this requirement, but your seems to be the solution and the linked site has some great info, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Posted as an answer (with a little more detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIFont` metrics include ascender, descender, cap height, x height, etc... all of which determines how the characters fit into a container. There is a good explanation and diagram here: http://cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont

If you really want to get the height (and/or width) of the individual character "glyphs" you'll need to use Core Text. This will include calling `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters()` and `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph()` to get the "glyph path" (a `CGPath` object), at which point you can get the "bounding box" to determine the exact size.

Lots of discussions and example code out there... A good starting point is simply searching for `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`